# Android, simpleframework PersistenceException

Tags: android, simple-framework

I am trying to use org.simpleframework.xml. classes to handle xml data on my Android project. I can't understand how to build my class "ChecklistGradeDetail" but i get this

```
01-09 14:56:05.615: WARN/System.err(896): org.simpleframework.xml.core.PersistenceException: Element 'ChecklistGradeDetail' declared twice at line -1
```

xml/rest

```
<ArrayOfChecklistGradeDetail xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TeamTask.Service" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<ChecklistGradeDetail>
    <ChecklistItemID>34</ChecklistItemID>
    <ChecklistItemText>requirements</ChecklistItemText>
    <Comments>please pass</Comments>
    <CreatedOn>2011-09-07T16:30:08.14</CreatedOn>
    <GradeDetailID>362</GradeDetailID>
    <NotPerformed>false</NotPerformed>
    <Preceptor>System Administrator</Preceptor>
    <Satisfactory>true</Satisfactory>
    <Unsatisfactory>false</Unsatisfactory>
    <UserID>admin</UserID>
</ChecklistGradeDetail>
<ChecklistGradeDetail>
    <ChecklistItemID>35</ChecklistItemID>
    <ChecklistItemText>write test</ChecklistItemText>
    <Comments>please pass</Comments>
    <CreatedOn>2011-09-07T16:30:08.14</CreatedOn>
    <GradeDetailID>363</GradeDetailID>
    <NotPerformed>false</NotPerformed>
    <Preceptor>System Administrator</Preceptor>
    <Satisfactory>true</Satisfactory>
    <Unsatisfactory>false</Unsatisfactory>
    <UserID>admin</UserID>
</ChecklistGradeDetail>
<ChecklistGradeDetail>
    <ChecklistItemID>36</ChecklistItemID>
    <ChecklistItemText>execute test</ChecklistItemText>
    <Comments>please pass</Comments>
    <CreatedOn>2011-09-07T16:30:08.14</CreatedOn>
    <GradeDetailID>364</GradeDetailID>
    <NotPerformed>false</NotPerformed>
    <Preceptor>System Administrator</Preceptor>
    <Satisfactory>true</Satisfactory>
    <Unsatisfactory>false</Unsatisfactory>
    <UserID>admin</UserID>
</ChecklistGradeDetail>
</ArrayOfChecklistGradeDetail>
```

ArrayofChecklistGradeDetail class

```
    @Root
public class ArrayOfChecklistGradeDetail {
    @ElementList(name="ChecklistGradeDetail")
    public ArrayList<ChecklistItems> Checklist;
}
```

ChecklistItem class

```
public class ChecklistItems {
    @Element(required=false)
    public String ChecklistItemID;
    @Element(required=false)
    public String ChecklistItemText;
    @Element(required=false)
    public String Comments;
    @Element(required=false)
    public String CreatedOn;
    @Element(required=false)
    public String GradeDetailID;
    @Element(required=false)
    public String NotPerformed;
    @Element(required=false)
    public String Preceptor;
    @Element(required=false)
    public String Satisfactory;
    @Element(required=false)
    public String Unsatisfactory;
    @Element(required=false)
    public String UserID;  

}
```

help :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the problem.
ArrayofCheclistGradeDetail class needed to be as follows

```
    @Root
public class ArrayOfChecklistGradeDetail {
    @ElementList(entry="ChecklistGradeDetail", inline=true)
    public ArrayList<ChecklistItems> Checklist;
```